# How to drop PostgreSQL database through command line

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to drop my database and create a new one through the command line. I log in using `psql -U username` and then do a `\connect template1`, followed by a `DROP DATABASE databasename;`.

I get the error

> database databasename is being accessed by other users

I shut down Apache and tried this again, but I'm still getting this error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you just run the `dropdb databasename` command from the command line?

Comment: It says "ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database"

Comment: Use `psql -U <user>  -c "drop database protodb"` (without database name)

Comment: This will restart postgres and disconnect everyone:
sudo service postgresql restart 
Then do a:
dropdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U "youruser" "testdb"
Notice the "" to make sure special characters go in without a hitch.

Comment: `drop database <dataabase_name>;` Don't forget the comma.

Comment: 1. `>psql -U postgres -h localhost`

2. `>drop database database;`

Comment: Perhaps you should post it on Database Administrators

Answer (score 579, accepted):

You can run the [dropdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-dropdb.html) command from the command line:

```
dropdb 'database name'
```

Note that you have to be a superuser or the database owner to be able to drop it.

You can also check the `pg_stat_activity` view to see what type of activity is currently taking place against your database, including all idle processes.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='database name';
```

Note that from PostgreSQL v13 on, you can disconnect the users automatically with

```
DROP DATABASE dbname WITH (FORCE);
```

or

```sh
dropdb -f dbname
```

Comment: I'm using `dropuser` command to remove also the user.

Comment: Not helpful answer as for version 9. The error about opened connections appears still.

Comment: This will restart postgres and disconnect everyone:
sudo service postgresql restart 
Then do a:
dropdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U "youruser" "testdb"
Notice the "" to make sure special characters go in without a hitch.

Comment: using the postgres user:  sudo -u postgres dropdb 'database name'

Comment: `\l` to see all the databases you have.

Comment: creating a connection from a different database than the one removing and executing this:
`DROP DATABASE dbname WITH (FORCE); `
totally solves the problem!!!

Answer (score 131):

This worked for me:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='YourDatabase';
```

for postgresql earlier than 9.2 replace `pid` with `procpid`

```
DROP DATABASE "YourDatabase";
```

http://blog.gahooa.com/2010/11/03/how-to-force-drop-a-postgresql-database-by-killing-off-connection-processes/

Comment: Had to change it a bit to work: `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='YourDatabase';`

Comment: `column "procpid" does not exist` for amazon RDS postgres 9.6 instance

Comment: Hm. Ran this, but it just reconnected immediately, after saying, "SSL connection closed unexpectedly [...] attempting to reset: Succeeded." Annnd, I'm back.

Answer (score 84):

Try this. Note there's no database specified - it just runs "on the server"

```
psql -U postgres -c "drop database databasename"
```

If that doesn't work, I have seen a problem with postgres holding onto orphaned prepared statements.
To clean them up, do this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_xacts;
```

then for every id you see, run this:

```
ROLLBACK PREPARED '<id>';
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to databases, so this is probably a stupid question, but where do I type this out? Before logging into the database right? And I should replace databasename with the name of my database right?

Comment: @iman453: You'd run that straight from your shell/command-line.

Comment: There's no such things as "just on the server" for postgresql.  You must connect to a database.  In this case you'll be connecting to the postgres database which is pretty much there just for cases like this.  And a good point on prepared transactions, but in that case you should get an error message saying that's the issue.

Comment: @Scott - no so. you can run "server" level commands *without* connecting to a specific database, such as drop/create database commands, as in the example in my answer.

Comment: Sorry Bohemian, but you are the one who's wrong.  Here's 

pg_stat_activity while running createdb from the command line:
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_activity ;
 11564 | postgres |   22223 |    16384 | smarlowe | CREATE DATABASE test;            | f       | 2011-08-19 16:18:26.918933-06 | 2011-08-19 16:18:26.918933-06 | 2011-08-19 16:18:26.916578-06 |             |          -1

Note that this happens while running createdb from the command line in another terminal.  That first field is the db that my createdb script was connected to

Comment: For further proof, drop your postgres database and try the createdb script command.  It'll then fail.

Comment: Interesting. So if you don't specify a database, you still get connected to the default "postgres" database. OK - thanks for the info. I didn't realise that. Nice research btw +1

Comment: yeah, the command line utils like createdb and createuser hit the maintenance db which by default is postgres.  In older versions it was template1 but this often got in the way of createdb etc, so that was changed and the postgres db was added to handle this job.

Comment: Why isn't this the top, #1 answer?

Comment: since my user isn't "postgres", I had to also add: `--dbname=postgres` to my command.

Comment: note this does not work for Amazon RDS. It boots you from the `psql` connection and performs an automatic reset and then you log back in and you're back to where you started.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me

Comment: Variant of this answer when your PostgreSQL user `postgres` is "peer authenticated" from system user `postgres`, as is the default under Ubuntu: `sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c "drop database databasename"`

Answer (score 19):

When it says users are connected, what does the query "select * from pg_stat_activity;" say?  Are the other users besides yourself now connected?  If so, you might have to edit your pg_hba.conf file to reject connections from other users, or shut down whatever app is accessing the pg database to be able to drop it.  I have this problem on occasion in production.  Set pg_hba.conf to have a two lines like this:

```
local   all         all                               ident
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          reject
```

and tell pgsql to reload or restart (i.e. either sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload or pg_ctl reload) and now the only way to connect to your machine is via local sockets.  I'm assuming you're on linux.  If not this may need to be tweaked to something other than local / ident on that first line, to something like host ... yourusername.

Now you should be able to do:

```
psql postgres
drop database mydatabase;
```