# Removing Migrations With Knex.js In My Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to get knex working in my node.js application. I was following a tutorial and at some point created a table but could not repeat the process. I removed the table and deleted all the migrations folders. At tis point I started over but after creating a new migration and then running `knex migrate:latest` I get an error saying the migration directory is corrupt because the original migration I had is missing.

I was under the impression that if the file is missing it should not know it was ever there.

What is the proper way to remove a migration from my project?

knexfile.js

```
 development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user:     'postgres',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'myDatabase'
    },
     pool: {
      min: 10,
      max: 20
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds/development'
    }
```

db.js

```
var config      = require('../knexfile.js');  
var env         = 'development';  
var knex        = require('knex')(config[env]);

module.exports = knex;
console.log('Getting knex');
knex.migrate.latest([config]); 
console.log('Applying migration...');
```

Running this gives error,

```
knex migrate:latest

Using environment: development
Error: The migration directory is corrupt, the following files are missing: 20161110130954_auth_level.js
```

but this migration does not exist because I deleted it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You had to rollback a migration (`knex migrate:rollback`) before deleting the file, I guess what you can do is:

`touch [full_path_to_migrations_here]/migrations/20161110130954_auth_level.js`

`knex migrate:rollback`

`rm [full_path_to_migrations_here]/migrations/20161110130954_auth_level.js`

Reference here
https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1569

Comment: In order to remove the migration I ended up going into the database and deleting the row that was relevant to the migration and then deleting the js file associated with it.

Comment: I still face the same issue .. it should be `ressetting` thing

Comment: Good solution but the file you are creating with `touch` needs empty up and down export functions.

Answer (score 9):

Your migration files have been deleted,
but they are still referenced in a table called "migrations"
(see update below), which was generated by knex.

You should be able to check it by connecting to your local database.

I faced the same problem and I solved it by removing records corresponding to my deleted migration files.

```
delete from migrations
where migrations."name" in ('20191027220145_your_migration_file.js', ...);
```

EDIT: The *migrations* table name might change according to [the options](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-CLI) or to the version you use.
The constant is set [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/0.20/bin/utils/constants.js) and used [there](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js).
To be sure of the name, you could [list all tables](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-list-all-tables) as suggested by @MohamedAllal.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

To **remove** either you **can** **rollback** and so rollback then remove.

Or you can not ! And follow on the bellow:

(> The bellow, answer too the following error which you may already get to see:<)

## Error: The migration directory is corrupt

Which will happens if

The migrations files are deleted, while the records on the migration table created by knex remains there!

**So simply clear them up!**

(remove then clear up, or clear up then remove!)

Important to note the migration table by now is `knex_migration`. Don't know if it was different in the past!

But better list the db tables to make sure!

I'm using postgres! Using psql :

```sh
> \d
```

i get :

[image]

You can do it with Raw SQL! Using your db terminal client, Or using knex itself! Or any other means  (an editor client (pgAdmin, mysql workbench, ...).

### Raw sql

```sql
DELETE FROM knex_migration
WHERE knex_migration."name" IN ('20200425190608_yourMigFile.ts', ...);
```

**Note** you can copy past the files from the error message (if you get it)

**ex:** 20200425190608_creazteUserTable.ts, 20200425193758_createTestTestTable.ts

from

> Error: The migration directory is corrupt, the following files are missing: 20200425190608_creazteUserTable.ts, 20200425193758_createTestTestTable.ts

Copy past! And it's fast!

(you can get the error by trying to migrate)

### Using knex itself

```
knex('knex_migration')
    .delete()
    .whereIn('name', ['20200425190608_yourMigFile.ts', ...]);
```

Create a script! Call your knex instance! Done! Cool!

After cleaning

[image]

The migrations will run nicely! And your directory no more corrupt!
How much i do love that green!

Happy coding!

## Removing a migration: (Bring it down then remove to remove)

What is the right way to remove a migration?

The answer is bring that one migration down and then remove it's file!

Illustration

```sh
$ knex migrate:down "20200520092308_createUsersWorksTable.ts"

$ rm migrations/20200520092308_createUsersWorksTable.ts
```

[image]

You can list the migrations to check as bellow

```sh
$ knex migrate:list
```

(from v0.19.3! if not available update knex (`npm i -g knex`))

## Alter migration to alter only (No)

If you are like me and like to update the migration directly in the base migration! And you may think about creating an alter migration! run it then remove it!

A fast flow! You just make the update on the base creation table! Copy past into the new created alter table! And run it then remove it!

**If you're thinking that way! Don't !!!**

You **can't rollback** because it's the changes that you want! You can't cancel them!

You can do it! And then you have to clear the records! Or you'll get the error! And just not cool!

**Better create an later file script!** Not a migration file! And run it directly! Done!

My preference is to create an `alter.ts` (.js) file in the Database folder!
Then create the alter schema code there! And create an npm script to run it!

[image]

Each time you just modify it! And run!

Here the base skeleton:

```
import knex from './db';

(async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await knex.schema.alterTable('transactions', (table) => {
            table.decimal('feeAmount', null).nullable();
        });
        console.log(resp);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

And better with vscode i just use run code (if run code extension is installed! Which is a must hhhh)!

[image]

And if no errors then it run well! And you can check the response!

You can check up the **schema api** in the doc!

Also to **alter** you'll need to use `alter()` method as by the snippet bellow that i took from the doc:

```
// ________________ alter fields
// drops previous default value from column, change type
// to string and add not nullable constraint
table.string('username', 35).notNullable().alter();
// drops both not null constraint and the default value
table.integer('age').alter();
```

Now happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

try to use the option below, it will do exactly what it refers to:

```js
migrations: {
 disableMigrationsListValidation: true,
}
```

[knex.js migration api](https://knexjs.org/#Migrations-API)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in development with your seeds and migration files that you are able to recreate the tables and data you can just drop and recreate the databases using the available knex migrations.

My development environment was using sqlite so `rm -rf dev.sqlite3` on terminal fixed this.

With postgresql it will be `dropdb "db_name"` on the terminal or [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073773/drop-postgresql-database-through-command-line)  for more alternatives.

This is simple and there is no need to do a *rollback* after that.

The record about your old migrations is gone and you can recreate it with a new `knex migrate:latest`.

Answer (score 1):

If using the postgresql on Heroku navigate to the database credentials and clicking the "Reset Database" button works

Comment: It did the trick for me, but beware that it's only advisable if you're dealing with a fresh database that's not in production yet!

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the database by running this command.

```
Heroku run pg:reset --confirm app-name
```

Comment: It did the trick for me, but beware that it's only advisable if you're dealing with a fresh database that's not in production yet!

Answer (score 0):

**Hot fix**

Issue is happening because the deleted migrations are still the `knex_migrations` table in the database so the `knex_migrations` table does not match with the migrations file in the working directory. You have to delete the migrations from the `knex_migrations` table.

delete
from knex_migrations km
where km."name" = 'deleted_migration.js'

Answer (score 0):

Go to the graphical user interface you are using to see the data in the database and inside tables, there will be two other tables along with the tables you made named knex_migrations and knex_migrations_lock. Delete both of these files and others tables that you created. Then run

```
knex migrate:latest
```

Caution: This will remove all data from the database(That's fine if you are using it for development)