# Remove old project dbs from macbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, macos

During my time in school and creating my own applications, I've had to delete projects from my laptop to free up space. Is there a way to remove the db from said deleted projects if the project is no longer on my computer? I've had an issue before , when I was starting out that I had to delete my project and start over. But I had forgotten to drop the db. So when I went to create the project again with the same name, it told me the db already exists.

So is there a way to remove stale dbs that do not correspond to a project anymore?

**EDIT** Sorry, I may need to clarfy. I am trying to clear up space on my laptop by remove old dbs that I forgot to drop before deleting the project folder. I no longer remember the names of the deleted projects

Comment: What database are where you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use postgres just log in as your Postgres user and run `\l`
You are going to see all the DBs you have, and then could drop them with: `dropdb 'database name'`.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073852/7611168

Answer (score 0):

If it says DB already exists then run

```
rake db:drop
```

It will drop the existing DB

Comment: Sorry, Ill edit the question, but I meant if I've deleted the project and want to free up space on my laptop